# Button that scrolls to an element with a sticky navbar, how?

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, sticky

so basically i am making a portfolio site. On this site i want a sticky navbar that stays in place when you scroll by it. Now also the buttons in the navbar, when clicked, should scroll me to the element linked to that button. The thing is because the navbar is there it scrolls just a little bit too far each time and i don't know to fix this.

What i tried is multiple things, first i tried doing this:
`<a href="#elementInQuestion">`
This would scroll to the right element but too far because the navbar is there.

Second i tried to do it a more javascript way. So the html for this would be something like this:

`<li id="projectsBtn" onclick="scrollTime();">Projecten</li>`

Then the javascript:

```
function scrollTime(){
  location.href = "#";
  location.href = "#projects";
  window.scrollBy(0, -108);
}
```

Now what this did is it negated the first 2 lines in the javascript function and only scrolled up 108 pixels. When i removed the scrollBy method it the page would scroll to the #projects div but it doesn't first scroll to the element and then scroll a little bit more up from that as i wanted it to here.

It was supposed to scroll to the element in question then scroll up an additional 108 pixels (because thats how big high the navbar is)

How would i make it so the buttons in the navbar, when clicked, always scroll to the right position? Because i'm completely lost here.

If you need the whole code of how the navbar looks and stuff just ask.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you need smooth scroll to section by clicking on the buttons in navbar.
You can do it without javascript.

```
<body> 
<div class="container">
 <div class="navbar">
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#about>ABOUT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
      <a href="#price-list>PRICE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section id="about">
    <h1>About</h1>
  </section>
  <section id="price-list">
    <h1>Price list</h1>
  </section>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
}


.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% !important;

/* CSS Scroll stuff */

    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
body{
    height:100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried putton this code in a sepperate document to isolate it and see if it works and it still has the issue where when you click the button its scrolls past the point when i want it to be, the navbar is ontop of the point where you want it to be. Do you have a  working example maybe?